# Simplest axiom that entails the existence of an infinite set

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, infinity, axioms

Let $\phi$ be a [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Formulas) in first-order logic without equality and with the binary relation $\in$.

Let the size $s(\phi)$ of a formula $\phi$ be given by the following inductive definition on the grammar of well-formed formulas:

\begin{align}
s(\forall x \phi) &= 1 + s(\phi) \\
s(\exists x \phi) &= 1 + s(\phi) \\
s(\neg \phi) &= 1 + s(\phi) \\
s(\phi \land \psi) &= 1 + s(\phi) + s(\psi) \\
s(\phi \lor \psi) &= 1 + s(\phi) + s(\psi) \\
s(\phi \rightarrow \psi) &= 1 + s(\phi) + s(\psi) \\
s(x \in y) &= 1
\end{align}

What is the smallest $\phi$ such that $\text{ZF}-\text{Infinity}+\phi\vdash\text{Infinity}$ and is not known to be inconsistent?

Consider, for example,

$$\exists x (\exists y (y \in x) \land \forall y (y \in x \rightarrow \exists z (y \in z \land z \in x)))$$

[*The Logically Simplest Form of the Infinity Axiom*](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1988-103-01/S0002-9939-1988-0938682-2/S0002-9939-1988-0938682-2.pdf) by Parlamento and Policriti also addresses this question but defines "simplicity" in terms of quantifier alternations, whereas I'm interested in the size of the formula.

Comment: Is there some particular reason you excude equality?  Equality is included in ZF...

Comment: Is there a particular reason you exclude $\neg$ and $\to$?

Comment: @EricWofsey I prefer to define equality explicitly (rather than implicitly in the background logic) using the [modified version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality#In_predicate_logic_without_equality) of the axiom of extensionality.

Comment: Perhaps you should specify the variant of ZF you have in mind, just in case the presence of some normally redundant axioms like empty-set makes a difference to the answer.

Comment: And I am one of those who think that the standard rules for equality are better, because they capture the abstracted notion of equality instead of expressing an implementation that only works in some set theories like ZFC. Consider the variety of useful first-order theories like PA, RCF, ACF and so on, that all use equality as a primitive undefined notion. Also, the definition of equality you prefer is simply the standard rules for equality unfolded for the specific language with a single binary predicate-symbol "$∈$", so it may fail if the language is expanded. =)

Comment: @user21820 I was considering extensionality, pairing, powerset, union, regularity, specification, and replacement.

Comment: @user21820 Fair enough, first-order logic with equality works as well.

Comment: @EricWofsey Forgot to explicitly mention that $\phi$ does *not* have to be a consequence of ZF. You can get a stronger theory.

Comment: @user76284: Okay so empty-set does not follow from your chosen axioms, because all of them are universal statements and can only be applied if you have some set to begin with. (My last comment was wrong, so I deleted it.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reminds me of [code-golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com). Here is a nice one (length $8$):

> $∃S\ ∀x\ ∃y\ ( y∈S ∧ ( x∈S ⇒ x∈y ) )$.

Let $I$ be such that $∀x\ ∃y\ ( y∈I ∧ ( x∈I ⇒ x∈y ) )$. Then (applying to $x:=I$) we get $∃y\ ( y∈I )$. Let $c_0∈I$. Then $∃y\ ( y∈I ∧ c_0∈y )$. Let $c_1∈I$ such that $c_0∈c_1$. Continuing in the same way we get $c_0∈c_1∈c_2∈\cdots$, all of which are members of $I$. By Foundation we can prove that any given two of them are distinct. But of course we want actual infinity, not the meta-observation that $I$ is infinite. We can first prove the generalization $∀x∈I\ ∃y∈I\ ( x∈y )$. After that it is easy if we have Choice or Collection. In particular, by AC we can let $f : I→I$ such that $x∈f(x)$ for every $x∈I$, and then let $N$ be the intersection of all subsets of $I$ that include $c_0$ and are closed under $f$, yielding something like Zermelo's original version.

It turns out that we can in fact proceed in ZF alone (without Choice). See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1270155) for the key idea. We basically define in ZF minus Infinity the [rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe) [of every set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_foundation#Every_set_has_an_ordinal_rank) $S$ (by applying Foundation to the set of unranked sets in the transitive closure of $S$). Then construct the set $R$ of all ranks of members of $I$. Now observe that every $k∈R$ is the rank of some $x∈I$, and $x∈y$ for some $y∈I$, and $y$ has a higher rank than $x$, so the transitive closure of $R$ is closed under successor. Therefore we recover the standard Infinity axiom.